# How to have another "alert" for every form in ajax requesting?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
  let getLoginPassSystem = function (getPassForgotSystem, getLoginCheckSystem) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login,#lostpasswordform,#register').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.virtuelles-museum.com.udev/spielelogin/logsystem.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
          var data = JSON.parse(response);

          if (data.success == "accepted") {
            document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = 'Herzlich Willkommen';

            // location.href = 'index.php';
          } else {
            alert('Ungültige Email oder Password!');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  })
}
```

Well, I want to have for every form(#login,#lostpasswordform,#register) an different "alert". Is it actually possible?

Comment: BTW I know if I do another Function it would work but I have to use in one function.

Comment: Just to be clear, there are multiple ways of achieving this.

Output wise all of the solutions will work for you, you'll to decide which one to go ahead with.

@raximjon's solution can be scalable for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save an alert massage in each div tag as data attribute. For example:

```
<div id="login" data-msg="message1"></div>
<div id="lostpasswordform" data-msg="message2"></div>
<div id="register" data-msg="message3"></div>


// then you can invoke them like this
let getLoginPassSystem = function (getPassForgotSystem, getLoginCheckSystem) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login,#lostpasswordform,#register').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let current_form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.virtuelles-museum.com.udev/spielelogin/logsystem.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
          var data = JSON.parse(response);

          if (data.success == "accepted") {
            document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = 'Herzlich Willkommen';

            // location.href = 'index.php';
          } else {
            alert(current_form.attr('data-msg')); 
          }
        }
      });
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've moved out from the scope.

Comment: Its actually right code but somehow it reloads my page.

Comment: Please, try to comment a changed parts of code and test. I think there is another code which occurs this issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can simply check the `e.target` - it will be different for every form.

You can get more information about `Event.target` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: It's always suggested to add a small snippet of code to explain how are you suggesting you on solving, else you can simple comment on the Original question.